# Waiting for response from Telegraf.js user

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegraf.js

Waiting for user response.  For example, the bot asks the user for his age, he enters it and the bot must catch his answer and send the next question.  How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply take a look at [Telegraf.js documentation](https://telegraf.js.org/) to know how.

To wait for a text message and reply, you can do this:

```js
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf");

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN); // Your bot api token

// waiting for messages and replying
bot.on("text", (ctx) => {
     ctx.reply("Hello World");
});

bot.start();
```

To answer to a specific question (Eg: what is your name) you can do *something* like this:

```
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf");

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN); // Your bot api token

let ask = false;
let name;

bot.on("text", (ctx) => {
     if(ask) {
          name = ctx.message.text;
     } else {
          ask = true;
          ctx.reply("What is your name?");
     }
});

bot.start();
```

Comment: Not a text message is acceptable, but a sequence of user messages.

Comment: Yes, I meant a message that contains text that sent by the user. Also you can reply to any message (not only text: images, videos, etc.). @RIXIN

Comment: Sorry, but no. Let's say we have a chain of questions that the user must answer. For example, the bot sends him a message with a question of age, he enters his age, the next question is how name. And how should I expect to enter his name? @UsithaDEV

Comment: Then edit your question with that example. I misunderstood you because you are not explained your question well. You asked **user** wants to ask a question, not the **bot**. Edit your question with those information and mention me; I'll edit my answer. :) @RIXIN

Comment: Ok.) No problem.